# Using Java.io.file, subdirectories can be found using one way but not another

Tags: java, file, directory, java-threads, java-19

In my school assignment, we are tasked with using threads to speed up a file searching algorithm. The original program they gave us was this:

```
package filefinder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileFinder {
    private final File rootDir;

    public FileFinder(String root) throws IOException {
        rootDir = new File(root);
        if (!(rootDir.exists() && rootDir.isDirectory())) {
            throw new IOException(root + " is not a directory");
        }
    }

    public void findFile(String file) {
        find(rootDir, file);
    }

    private void find(File rootDir, String fileName) {
        File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    System.out.println("Found at: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    find(file, fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called in the main file:

```
package filefinder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String goal = "needle.txt";
            String root = "haystack";
            FileFinder ff = new FileFinder(root);
            ff.findFile(goal);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This finds the file. Then, to run it with threads, I tried to split it into 5 threads, 1 for each of the 5 subdirectories.

```
package filefinder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String goal = "needle.txt";
            String root = "haystack";
            File file = new File(root);
            File[] children = file.listFiles();
            System.out.println(children);
            for (File child : children)
            {
                if (child.isDirectory()){
                    new FileFinder(child.getName());}
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Yet now, it throws the exception "haystack1 is not a directory". Why is it not able to find the subdirectories this way? Thank you.

I did managed to run it with threads, but it didn't improve performances at all. A classmate of mine said it was because I defined a new thread during each iteration of the for-loop, which is why here I'm trying to just create a new thread for each of the direct subdirectories, so the 5 folders inside of the main folder.

The folder we're searching through is called 'haystack', containing 5 folders called 'heystack1' to 'heystack5', each with the same 5 folders until a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're passing only the file name, to *FileFinder*.

Which, is technically just the last element within the path.

You'll need to pass the entire path.

You can use *[File#getPath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getPath())* for the relative path, and *[File#getAbsolutePath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getPath())* for the absolute path.
Similarly, you can use *[File#getAbsoluteFile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile())* to return the value as a *File* object.

```java
new FileFinder(child.getAbsolutePath());
```

```java
new FileFinder(child.getPath());
```

Comment: The 3rd code block doesn't work for me while the 2nd one does, in case you were talking about the 2nd one.

Comment: @user12456500, I overlooked that.  I've updated my answer.